# SQL select on condition

Tags: sql

I have a table like below,

```
ID | Amt
-------
1  | $30
2  | $2
3  | $50
```

I want to do a select on the amount based on the ID and the thing is that ID=1 is not guarantee to be there.  So, I want to check if ID=1 exist then I select the amount correspond to the ID=1 else I want to select the amount where ID=2.

So something like,

```
Select (If ID= 1 then amt else amt(for ID2) from Table
```

How can I achieve this Sql select statement?

Thanks.
.

Comment: The best answer might depend on which RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what if 1 and 2 aren't there? if it's always going to drop through to the next id you should select the first item in there ordered by id.

```
select top 1 amt from table order by id;
```

Syntax for this might be off a bit...I'm jumping between dbs currently...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, there may be a better way... Without knowing more, this is my answer:

MSSQL:

```
select top 1 * from myTable where ID >= 1 order by ID
```

MySQL:

```
select * from myTable where ID >= 1 order by ID limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`select Amt 
from theTable
where ID in
 (select min(ID) 
 from theTable
 where (ID < 3)
)`

Comment: If you just want the smallest id...just remove the "where (ID < 3)" out of the where clause and it will return the "smallest" id.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, amt from table where id = ( select min( id ) from table )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle-specific answer.

It's not clear how general a solution you want.

For hardcoded values 1 and 2:

```
select amt from (
  select amt from table where id between 1 and 2 order by id asc
) where rownum =1
```

Replace 1 and 2 with `n` and `n+1` to generalize for any starting value `n`.

Remove the upper bound of 2 if you really want to find the lowest existing ID greater than the one you passed in, regardless of how high it is.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use EXISTS stament and create a function
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-exists

Answer (score 0):

If database is SQL Server you can achieve this with a CASE State

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the record with the lowest ID

For MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL use limit

```
select amt from tbl order by id limit 1;
```

For SQL Server, Sybase use top

```
select top 1 amt from tbl order by id;
```

For Oracle use rownum

```
SELECT * FROM (select amt from tbl order by id) X WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

For an ANSI SQL92 approach

```
SELECT AMT FROM TBL WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TBL)
```